# How incremental refresh on Materialized view works?

Tags: oracle, view, materialized-views

Say I have a below query which is constructing materialized view(MV)
    `select * from employee, department where employee.id = department.id and name like '%Andy%'`

I have two related questions on How incremental update on MV works  internally

1) Say I insert or update any entry either in employee or department table, can I configure `increment refresh` on MV to be asynchronous of insert/update transaction 
or it is mandatory to be synchronous process ?

2)While insert or update , Does oracle evaluate(through transactionl logs) each updated/inserted row and apply the MV query criteria , see if satisfies it . If yes, update or insert the row in MV ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) Say I insert or update any entry either in employee or department table, can I configure increment refresh on MV to be asynchronous of insert/update transaction or it is mandatory to be synchronous process ?

If you want to have data available on a materialized view as soon as changes are committed on the base table then you can use [ON COMMIT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/refresh.htm#DWHSG8364) refresh method.

Or if you want to refresh by incrementally applying changes to the materialized view then you can use [FAST](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/refresh.htm#DWHSG8364) refresh method. You can do this asynchronously.

> 2)While insert or update , Does oracle evaluate(through transactionl logas) each updated/inserted row and apply the MV query criteria , see if satisfies it . If yes, update or insert the row in MV ?

It depends upon what kind of refresh method you are using. If you are using FAST or ON COMMIT refresh method then yes, it only applies the changes to the MV which satisfy the criteria defined in the query used to create the MV.

Answer (score 1):

For FAST REFRESH you have to create `MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG` on base tables you select for the MV. In these materialized view logs Oracle stores updated/inserted/deleted row information. i.e. Oracle does not use the REDO logs as you presumed.

Once all MViews based on your table are refreshed (either by ON COMMIT or manual REFRESH) content of according materialized view logs are truncated.